# How can I add or subtract timezone offset using dayjs?

Tags: javascript, timezone, nestjs, dayjs

I am creating open/close times (business hours) for a location. Currently I am storing this as a json object in a postgress table. This is what a sample looks like:

```
{
    "dayOfTheWeek": "FRIDAY",
    "isOpen": true,
    "hours": [
        {
            "open": "08:00",
            "closed": "12:00"
        },
        {
            "open": "13:00",
            "closed": "22:00"
        }
   ]
},
```

In this example, my location, my location is open 8am - 12pm. There is an hour break and it opens again at 1pm and closes at 10pm (central time).

I am also storing the location's timezone in another column like so

```
"timezone": "America/Chicago",
```

I am trying to display the open/close time(s) in the correct timezone. Currently, I am always showing time that is `+5` hours.

Here is what my code looks like. I am passing in a date/time string `2023-04-14T09:00:00`

```
// dateTimeStart = 2023-04-14T09:00:00


const selectedDay = dayjs(dateTimeStart).format('dddd').toUpperCase();  // FRIDAY

for (let day of location.businessHours) {
    if (selectedDay === day.dayOfTheWeek) {
        if (day.isOpen) {
            let blockStart = dayjs(block.open, 'HH:mm');   // 2023-04-14T13:00:00.000Z
            let blockStop = dayjs(block.closed, 'HH:mm');  // 2023-04-14T17:00:00.000Z
            
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Given that I am storing the timezone, how can I convert the `13:00` to `8:00` to show the correct time for the location's timezone?

I have tried using different forms of the timezone and utc offset plugins, but no luck.

```
let now = dayjs();
console.log(now.toString());                       // Fri, 14 Apr 2023 14:41:04 GMT
console.log(now.tz(location.timezone).toString()); // Fri, 14 Apr 2023 14:41:04 GMT
```

It's always logging the same times. I have also tried [setting a default timezone](https://day.js.org/docs/en/timezone/set-default-timezone) but I am still getting `13:00` instead of `8:00`

Doing this works:

```
console.log(now.tz(location.timezone).subtract(5, 'hour').toString()); // Fri, 14 Apr 2023 09:42:49 GMT
```

What is the ideal way to convert `America/Chicago` to `-5` so I can show the correct time for any given location?

**EDIT**

First, thank you for your patience @Mister Jojo.

What I am trying to accomplish is check that for any given time, if a location is open (or falls between the open/closed range).

For example (using Postman) I am passing in this as the date/time I am checking: `2023-04-14T09:00:00Z` 9:00am on April 14th.

I am handling that like so:

```
let requestedDateTimeStart = dayjs(dateTimeStart);

console.log('requested start time: ', requestedDateTimeStart.toISOString()); // requested start time:  2023-04-14T09:00:00.000Z
```

When I am checking to see if a location is open, I am doing it like this:

```
...
for (let block of day.hours) {
    let blockStart = dayjs(block.open, 'HH:mm');
    let blockStop = dayjs(block.closed, 'HH:mm');

    if (requestedDateTimeStart.isBefore(blockStart)) {
        console.log('BEFORE');
    } else {
        console.log('AFTER');
    }
    ...
```

I am always getting into the `BEFORE` block since 9 is before 13. I'm not comparing apples to apples & I'm not sure how to get to equal comparisons.

Comment: I don't understand your question, you already have the opening hours and the linked timezone.
and your question says you want to display the same!

Comment: Ha! Yeah, that's my biggest problem. I don't really understand what I'm doing...
In my second block I am open from `13:00` to `22:00` I am guessing that's ok to store the time like that, but I'd like to show in the UI `1:00pm` to `10:00pm`.

Comment: otherwise, for chicago UTC offet ion Standard Time (STD) is -6h,  and Daylight Saving Time (DST) is -5h.

Comment: why not put your question in practical terms? Want to show if a store in Chicago is currently open while you're in California or anywhere in the world ?

Comment: it seems to me that you are doing things backwards. you must first base yourself on the local time zone and convert it into the target time zone to find out if it is in the time range, and if necessary deduce your local time range.

Comment: Why ignoring my answer?, it gives me the feeling that at best you are only interested in my code and not the person who writes it.

Comment: Hii @MisterJojo - I appreciate your suggestion! Unfortunately, I have not been able to get back into this project just yet. I am thankful for such an elaborate answer & looking forward to giving it a try!

Answer (score 0):

It took me a little time, but I ended up finding a way to know the time offset from a TimeZone, for the current day.

this consists of calculating the time difference between the date/time of the day in zero GMT with the date/time on the chosen time zone. `{ timeZone: 'Etc/GMT'}` / `{ timeZone: 'America/Chicago'}`

code!

```js
const OpenTimes = 
  { name     : 'xxx'
  , timezone : 'America/Chicago' 
  , weekDays :
    [ { dayOfTheWeek : 'MONDAY'
      , isOpen       : true
      , hours        : [{ open: '13:00', closed: '22:00' }] 
      } 
    , { dayOfTheWeek : 'TUESDAY'
      , isOpen       : true
      , hours        : [{ open: '08:00', closed: '12:00' }, { open: '13:00', closed: '22:00' }] 
      } 
    , { dayOfTheWeek : 'WEDNESDAY'
      , isOpen       : true
      , hours        : [{ open: '08:00', closed: '12:00' }, { open: '13:00', closed: '22:00' }] 
      } 
    , { dayOfTheWeek : 'THURSDAY'
      , isOpen       : true
      , hours        : [{ open: '08:00', closed: '12:00' }, { open: '13:00', closed: '22:00' }] 
      } 
    , { dayOfTheWeek : 'FRIDAY'
      , isOpen       : true
      , hours        : [{ open: '08:00', closed: '12:00' }, { open: '13:00', closed: '22:00' }] 
      } 
    , { dayOfTheWeek : 'SATURDAY'
      , isOpen       : true
      , hours        : [{ open: '08:00', closed: '12:00' }] 
      } 
    , { dayOfTheWeek : 'SUNDAY'
      , isOpen       : false
      , hours        : [] 
  } ] };
  
const get_DteTim_val_enUS = str =>   // Friday, 4/14/2023, 22:50
  {
  let
    [ dayName, M, D, Y, Hr,Mn ] = str.split(/[\s,-]+|\/|\:/).map(v=>isNaN(v)?v.toUpperCase().trim():Number(v))
  , timeMinutes                 = (Hr * 60) + Mn
  , dayNun                      = OpenTimes.weekDays.findIndex( ({dayOfTheWeek}) => dayOfTheWeek === dayName )    
    ;
  return ({dayName, dayNun , M, D, Y, Hr,Mn, timeMinutes })
  // {"dayName":"FRIDAY","dayNun":4,"M":4,"D":14,"Y":2023,"Hr":22,"Mn":50,"timeMinutes":1370}
  }

const HM2str = (h,m) => h.toString(10).padStart(2, '0') + ':' + m.toString(10).padStart(2, '0');
 
const isOpenNow = (dayVal, timeVal) => 
  {
  let Schedule = OpenTimes.weekDays.find(({dayOfTheWeek})=> dayOfTheWeek === dayVal );
  return  Schedule.isOpen && Schedule.hours.reduce((resp,{open,closed})=>(resp||=(timeVal>=open && timeVal<=closed)),false);
  }

const
  myTable        = document.querySelector('#my-table')
, currentDate    = new Date()
, oneDay         = 24 * 60 // 24hours is 24 * 60 minutes
, dateOptions    = { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', weekday: 'long', hour12:false, year:'numeric', month:'numeric', day:'numeric' }
  ;

const 
  current_UTC_zero_str  = currentDate.toLocaleString('en-US', Object.assign({ timeZone: 'Etc/GMT'}, dateOptions))
, current_Chicago_DTstr = currentDate.toLocaleString('en-US', Object.assign({ timeZone: 'America/Chicago'}, dateOptions))
, UTC_0_DT              = get_DteTim_val_enUS( current_UTC_zero_str  )
, Chicago_DT            = get_DteTim_val_enUS( current_Chicago_DTstr )
, Chicago_DT_offset     = calc_Time_Offset( Chicago_DT )
, Chicago_UTC_part1     = `${Chicago_DT.Y}-${Chicago_DT.M.toString(10).padStart(2,'0')}-${Chicago_DT.D.toString(10).padStart(2,'0')}`    
  ;
//console.log( 'actual-time offset Chicago', Chicago_DT_offset, '(may change STD <-> DST )')
 

myTable.caption.innerHTML = '<b>actual</b> Chicago DT = ' + current_Chicago_DTstr 
                          + '<br>TZ identifier = Etc/GMT<b>' + Chicago_DT_offset + '</b>'
                          + '<br><i>(your local DT is ' + currentDate.toLocaleString('en-US', dateOptions) + ')</i>'
                          + '<br><small>is in an open range : ' + isOpenNow( Chicago_DT.dayName, HM2str(Chicago_DT.Hr, Chicago_DT.Mn)) + '</small>'

// console.log('UTC_0_DT'  , JSON.stringify(UTC_0_DT)  )
// console.log('Chicago_DT', JSON.stringify(Chicago_DT) )

myTable.querySelector('tHead th').textContent = Chicago_DT.dayName


if (!OpenTimes.weekDays[Chicago_DT.dayNun].isOpen)
  {
  myTable.querySelector('tHead tr th:nth-of-type(2)').textContent = 'day off';
  }
else
  {
  let row=null,dUTC='';
  OpenTimes.weekDays[Chicago_DT.dayNun].hours.forEach( elm =>
    {
    ['open','closed'].forEach( ref =>
      {
      row  = myTable.insertRow();
      dUTC = new Date(`${Chicago_UTC_part1}T${elm[ref]}:00.000${Chicago_DT_offset}`);
      row.insertCell().textContent = ref;
      row.insertCell().textContent = elm[ref];
      row.insertCell().textContent = dUTC.toLocaleString('en-US', dateOptions );
      })
    })
  }
 
function calc_Time_Offset({dayNun,timeMinutes})
  {
  let
    calcmn    = timeMinutes          + ((((UTC_0_DT.dayNun+1)%7) === dayNun) ? oneDay : 0)
  , utcZmn    = UTC_0_DT.timeMinutes + (((dayNun+1)%7) === (UTC_0_DT.dayNun) ? oneDay : 0)
  , sign      = calcmn > utcZmn ? '+' : '-'
  , delta_mns = calcmn > utcZmn ? calcmn - utcZmn : utcZmn - calcmn
  , tzM       = delta_mns % 60
  , tzH       = (delta_mns - tzM ) / 60  
    ;
  return `${sign}${ HM2str(tzH, tzM)}`
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
  }
table {
  margin           : 1rem;
  border-collapse  : separate;
  border-spacing   : 1px;
  background-color : lightslategrey ; /* all borders color  */
  }
th { 
  min-width        : 2.4rem;
  padding          : .2rem 1rem .1rem 1rem;
  background-color : #82bfca; 
  }
td {
  min-width        : 2.4rem;
  padding          : .2rem 1rem .1rem 1rem;
  text-align       : center;
  background-color : whitesmoke;
  }
caption {
  padding    : 1rem;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  }
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <caption></caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <th> weekDay </th>
      <th> local days &amp; times</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```